# Milliseconds to LocalDateTime

Tags: java

How to convert `long` milliseconds to `LocalDateTime`?

I have an old code which does some actions with calendar and I want to convert the result milliseconds to LocalDateTime.

```
final Calendar aMinuteAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
aMinuteAgo.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
//Convert aMinuteAgo.getTimeInMillis() to LocalDateTime
```

Comment: LocalDateTime ofInstant = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(aMinuteAgo.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

Comment: That would work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Calendar` can be converted `LocalDateTime`. Here is the sample code
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.ZoneId;
    import java.util.Calendar;

```
public class LDTTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Calendar aMinuteAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
        aMinuteAgo.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
        System.out.println(aMinuteAgo.getTime());
        LocalDateTime ofInstant = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(aMinuteAgo.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(ofInstant);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LocalDateTime ofInstant = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(aMinuteAgo.toInstant(),ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

If you dont want to use default zoneId use this code(optional) to get available time zones.

```
    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> allZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
        List<String> zoneList = new ArrayList<String>(allZones);
        Collections.sort(zoneList);

        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
        for (String s : zoneList) {
          ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(s);
          ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
          ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();
          String out = String.format("%35s %10s%n", zone, offset);
          System.out.println(out);
        }
      }
}
```

use one of codes in place of **ZoneId.systemDefault()**